# Acces STI type on create view and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, types, view, sti

Hello guys I've a a 2 model client and meal.

**client.rb**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :meals
accepts_nested_attributes_for :meals

end
```

**meal.rb**

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :client
end

class Lunch < Meal
end

class Dessert < Meal
end
```

**views/clients/_form.html.erb**

```
    <%= simple_form_for @client do |f| %>

    <%=f.input :name %>
    <%=f.input :adress %>
    <%=f.input :telephone %>

   <%= f.simple_fields_for :meal do |m| %>
    <%=m.input :type %>
    <%end%>
  <% end %>
```

When I save the meal type it doesn't appear on client' index.html.erb(it's blank).
What the problem is?
How can I create a client by giving him a meal type(eg."Lunch") with the following cotroller:

```
def create
  @client = Client.new(params[:client])

  respond_to do |format|
  if @client.save
    format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Operation was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @client, status: :created, location: @client }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matter i simply have to set the column inheritance in **meal.rb** like this:

```
class Meal < ActiveRecord::Base

    set_inheritance_column do
        "type" + "_id"
    end 

belongs_to :client
end

class Lunch < Meal
end

class Dessert < Meal
end
```

So now I can select the type of meal when I create a client.
Thanks to [Anan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80368/anand), the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311670/why-rails-doesnt-save-type-field-in-single-table-inheritance) comes from him.